# how to run PBS (portable batch system) with multiple user environment?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

Recently I finished configuration a PBS for my institute. It can run very well with a user, pbs. However, it can not be run with different user, for example, jhsong. It gives the following message:

```
echo "sleep 1" | qsub
socket_connect_unix failed: 15137
qsub: cannot connect to server (null) (errno=15137) could not connect to trqauthd
```

I think PBS should work at multiple user environment. But, I don't know how to configure. Can I solve this problem?

Best,

Je-Hoon Song

Answer (score 2):

Start "trqauthd" and "pbs_server" services and try to run

Answer (score 0):

Your error isn't caused by having problems resolving the user, it is because the trqauthd daemon isn't running. It needs to be started as root in order to submit jobs.

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: trqauthd is a daemon which runs as root whose only purpose is to tell pbs_server that the client command is originating from a specific user on a specific box. The error message says "could not connect to trqauthd" because trqauthd isn't running on the host where the client command originates.